# jquery datatable is not fully occupying the width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Hi I am using Jquery datatable which is aligned in page (internally using bootstrap css). The datatable which is generated is not fully occupying the entire width of the page.
Html code i am using is following.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-striped table-bordered dataTable dataTable-scroll-x">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

With this Jsfiddle user can drag the columns to see its detached.: http://jsfiddle.net/rhkvhcnb/1/

Comment: improved code formatting

Comment: provide a fiddle , and help us to reproduce the issue else we cant help with just seeing the image and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

- Remove `autoWidth: false`
- Add `width="100%"` attribute to `<table>` (there maybe width calculation bug in jQuery DataTables, I had to use `width="99.9%"` instead to account for table borders)

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhkvhcnb/2/) for code and demonstration.